# Posting Values of select box and hidden fields With Ajax on select box change

Tags: php, ajax

I am having a form in table with select box in each row carrying different information with hidden field in each row obtained from database in php, While selecting any of the option of the select box it should be redirected to another page with the hidden field in that row and the selected value of the select box

```
<table border="1px solid black">
<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Sub</th><th>Action</th></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Mamta</td><td>PHP</td><td><form method="post" action="form.php">
<select name="workno">
<option value="">--Select---</option><option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option></select>         
<input type="text" name="counter" placeholder="hidden Field">
<input type="text" name="counter" placeholder="hidden Field">
<input type="text" name="counter" placeholder="hidden Field">
<tr><td>2</td><td>Shipra</td><td>PHP</td>
<td><form method="post" action="form.php">
<select name="workno">
<option value="">--Select---</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>         
<input type="text" name="counter" placeholder="hidden Field">
<input type="text" name="counter" placeholder="hidden Field">
<input type="text" name="counter" placeholder="hidden Field">
```

How can i do that using Ajax, [here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/b9L12ajg/)

Comment: But if you want to redirect to another page, why use Ajax? :)

Comment: Any other solution to it

Comment: There are multiple guides in there but for example: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#entry-examples What you need to do to call this ajax, is to write something like this: `$("#workno").change(function() { ... }` I currently can't write entire code but just how to start.